# Placing variables inside formulas that require cell reference

Tags: vba, offset

I am attempting to create a macro that creates X amount of named formulas that use the offset formula.  The X will represent the number of data series (columns) that are on sheet1. This is how I want this to look for one of them to be created.

```
formula = offset($b$2,$a$2,0,$a$3,1)
activeworkbook.names.add Name:="test", Refers to:=formula
```

But I'm going to use a do loop until i = # of columns with values.  So this is my best shot at this, and i'm sure there are plenty of errors because i can't make it run:

```
columns = activesheet.countif((1:1),"*"
i = 5 
do until i = columns

'This is where i want to define my static cells location (not value) to be referenced in the formula
    pan = cells(1,2)
    zoom = cells(1,3)

'This is where i want to define my dynamic cells location (not value) based on the current column
    series = cells(2,i)

'This is where i want to create a name formulas specific to each series
    formula = "=offset(" & series & "," & pan & ",0" & zoom & ",1)
    activeworkbook.names.add name:=cells(1,i), refersto:=formula
```

So my results are basically, I get a new name formula but the reference formula is filled with integers and not the actual cell address. This is because I'm using a formula that calls the cell's value rather than pasting the cells address.

Any help would be great.

Comment: have you tried  CELLS.ADDRESS ?

Comment: could you please give some idea what you have in Cells(2,i)? just any expample...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what i was doing wrong.  When i recorded the macro, i didn't realize that it put

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Height___zoom", RefersToR1C1:="=Data!R5C1"
```

Now I can simply make the do lop with the

```
columns = activesheet.countif((1:1),"*"
i = 5 
do until i = columns

pan = "R1C2"
zoom = "R1C3"

series = "R2C" & i

formula = "=offset(" & series & "," & pan & ",0" & zoom & ",1)
activeworkbook.names.add name:=cells(1,i), refersto:=formula
```

Or something like that.  Still gotta work some kinks out to make it actually run correctly, but i found out the formula uses R#C# to refer to the cell's location.